Conceptual understanding of the Néron–Severi group
I'm trying to understand the importance of the Néron–Severi group $\operatorname{NS}(X)$ when $X$ is, say a complex manifold. My background is in the analytic side so I'm much more familiar with line bundles than divisors and it would seem that these two give two different ways to view $\operatorname{NS}(X)$.
From the analytic point of view, we have the first Chern class map $$c_1 : \operatorname{Pic}(X) \to H^2(X,\Bbb Z).$$
This has kernel $\operatorname{Pic}^0(X) := \ker(c_1)$ which I think is called the Picard variety. Basically this consists of isomorphism classes of holomorphic line bundles that are only topologically trivial.
Wikipedia states that $\operatorname{NS}(X)$ is identified with the image of $c_1$ in $H^2(X,\Bbb Z)$, but isn't this just $H^2(X,\Bbb Z) \cap H^{1,1}(X)$ by the Lefschetz theorem on $(1,1)$-classes?
The algebraic viewpoint seems to be that we switch from line bundles to divisors and think about $\operatorname{NS}(X)$ as the group of divisors modulo algebraic equivalence.
Is it reasonable to ask, what does this "divisors modulo algebraic equivalence" translate in the analytic side? This may be just an issue from me not understanding the equivalence between line bundles and divisor properly so I apologize my ignorance. Also, I would appreciate any heuristic views on why $\operatorname{NS}(X)$ should be of importance.

Sorry for my ignorance. You said that the analytic point of view is the same as the algebraic point of view. I googled, and only found relevant results for smooth projective complex varieties, not for arbitrary smooth varieties. Do you restrict to this special case?

Yes, I'm mostly looking at smooth projective varieties or polarized algebraic varieties. @Z.M

$\DeclareMathOperator\NS{NS}$Your understanding is correct — the only error is the word "just" which seems to reflect the assumption that because the Néron–Severi group can be explicitly described as the intersection  $H^2(X,\Bbb Z) \cap H^{1,1}(X)$ then that means it can't be very interesting.
Let me try to explain why this is wrong. First note that the intersection $H^2(X,\Bbb Z) \cap H^{1,1}(X)$  is a subtler object then each of the sets $H^2(X,\Bbb Z) $ and $H^{1,1}(X)$  that are being intersected: Both $H^2(X,\Bbb Z)$ and $H^{1,1}(X)$ are preserved when $X$ is deformed (actually for $H^{1,1}(X)$ I don't remember if this holds for non-Kähler manifolds, but certainly in the Kähler case) in the sense that there isomorphism class (as an abelian group and a vector space respectively) is fixed by deformation. However, the rank of $\NS(X)$ can change when the space is deformed. So the intersection description does not at all mean that we understand $\NS(X)$ if we understand $H^2(X,\Bbb Z) $ and $H^{1,1}(X)$.
But now let me say why $\NS(X)$ is interesting. As you say the kernel of the map $c_1$ consists of holomorphic line bundles that are topologically trivial. So the image consists of topological line bundles that can be given a holomorphic structure. Thus the image describes the part of some topological object (the set of isomorphism classes of topological line bundles) that we can "see" holomorphically.
$\NS(X)$ is also a natural setting for working with line bundles. If I want to prove some property for line bundles on a variety, and I first check this property is preserved under deformation of line bundles, then I only need to check it for one representative of each Néron–Severi class. I could try the same reasoning using topological classes of line bundles but then I would be stuck since some topological classes don't have any holomorphic representative.
In the divisor perspective, things are pretty much the same: Associated to any closed topological submanifold in $X$ we obtain a cohomology class in $H^2(X,\mathbb Z)$. The cohomology classes that can actually arise from holomorphic submanifolds are contained in the smaller set $\NS(X)$, so when considering holomorphic submanifolds we want to restrict attention to $\NS(X)$. Again we have some topological object and want to restrict to the part we can "see" holomorphically.

To (over-)elaborate a bit on your second paragraph: a picture I find useful is to view $H^2(X,\mathbb Z)$ as a fixed lattice inside $H^2(X,\mathbb C)$, while $H^{1,1}(X)$ is a subspace that is "moving around" inside $H^2(X,\mathbb C)$. As we deform $X$ and this subspace "moves around" it sometimes "lands on" more of the lattice points, meaning that the rank of NS jumps up.

This sounds like an interesting view. Do you happen to have an example illustrating this? @LazzaroCampeotti
